# PHP how to prevent page redirection after mail send?

Tags: jquery, ajax, email, php

I've got 2 seperate file with same code. contact.html and contact.php
I used contact.html for ajax call to load content inside, and contact.php for sending a mail. But I don't want to people redirect to contact.php cause page is crashed. (you can also try to fill the forms and see my problem)
What I want to; Is it possible to give "message sent successfully" message bottom of the send button and still stay in the same page with no redirect?

[click here to see the page](http://unidef.com.tr/yy/#contact)

content/contact.php and content/contact.html code

```
<div class="section group">
        <!-- Contact Form -->
        <div id="contact-form" class="col span_6_of_12">
            <h2 class="main-heading">
                <span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Me!</span>
            </h2>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("hiamina@asdkasd.com", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
?>  


   <form method="post" action="content/contact.php" id="contactform">
                <p>
                    <label for="name">
                        <b> Your Name</b>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="name" name="name" class="input" placeholder="type here">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="email">
                        <b> Your Email</b>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="input" placeholder="type here">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="message">
                        <b> Your Message</b>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="6" id="textarea"></textarea>
                </p>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" value="Send your message" class="send">
            </form>




        </div>
    <!-- /Contact Form -->


            <div id="space" class="col span_1_of_12"></div>


        <!-- Adress -->
        <div id="adress-container" class="col span_5_of_12">

            <h3><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Get in touch</h3>
            <hr>
            <p>Malis do cernantur qui cillum ullamco sed aliqua fore. Quem in ubi illum doctrina, consequat id multos tempor, senserit multos te admodum comprehenderit, an quem lorem o incurreret ut multos comprehenderit fabulas eram voluptate hic</p>

        </div>
        <!-- /Adress -->

    </div>
```

Comment: I think it is a better idea to look at why your contact.php is crashing.. because it might be a problem with sending the email.

Comment: I think if you are using ajax then you should do that way.

Comment: I don;t see any AJAX in your page by the way.. you are just submitting your form to content/contact.php

Comment: you have problem in php or ajax side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent page reloading with php forms,you need to use Ajax for this purpose like this

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){

var emailid= "hiamina@asdkasd.com"

jQuery.post("mails.php", {

email:$("#email").val(),
subject:$("#subject").val(),
message:$("#message").val(),
emailid:emailid


},  function(data, textStatus){

if( data == 1)
{
alert("Mail not sent");
e.preventDefault(); 
}
else
{
alert("Mail sent");
e.preventDefault(); 
}

});

});
```

mails.php

```
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_POST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_POST['message'] ;
  $emailid= $_POST['emailid'] ;
  if(mail($emailid, $subject, $message, "From:" . $email))
  echo "2";
else
echo "1";
```

also change this

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" value="Send your message" class="send">
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="submit" name="send" value="Send your message" class="send">
```

Comment: its works but this time content of mail is not included the mail :) and when you hit submit button it's send a lot of mail until you stop to click it.  and also there is no alert message show.

Comment: try removing <form> tag from html part.

Answer (score 2):

You should post it with ajax, this will stop it from changing the page, and you will still get the information back.

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'submit.php',
            data: { username: $(this).name.value, 
                    password: $(this).password.value }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
})
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You have a form action which is posting the data in content/contact.php, you can do it in 2 ways

- if you post to the above page then after the email sending script is done then you can use header() or javascript redirect to the contact.html page. You can set your message in a session and display that after re-direct, but for that the page should be able to execute PHP script (contact.html)
- Use Ajax to post the data in the  content/contact.php on submitting the form and on success display the message.

Answer (score -1):

i dont see your ajax section here
but every time you can use `exit` after the mail and echo to avoid redirection
first create an html file name `email.html`

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#contactform').submit(function() {
var name = $('#name').val();
var email =$('#email').val();
var value =$('#textarea').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'email.php',
            data: { name:name ,email:email ,text:value  }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
})
</script>
<form method="post" action="content/contact.php" id="contactform">
                    <p>
                        <label for="name">
                            <b> Your Name</b>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="name" id="name" class="input" placeholder="type here">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="email">
                            <b> Your Email</b>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="email" id="email" class="input" placeholder="type here">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="message">
                            <b> Your Message</b>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="6" id="textarea"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" value="Send your message" class="send">
                </form>
```

then save this below code in other page as `email.php`:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("hiamina@asdkasd.com", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
   exit;
  }
?>
```

done!